# flutter downloader generated plugin registrant error

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Adding flutter_downloader: ^1.6.1 in the pubspec. gives the following error

```
android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:16: error: package vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader does not exist
flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.FlutterDownloaderPlugin());
                                                              ^
```

1 error

What may be causing this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case installing the flutter sdk solved the problem. It was a error from flutter side.